# Can information extracted with Google's ML pose detection API be converted to point values in 3D coordinate system?

Tags: flutter, matrix, google-mlkit

I'm trying to draw a 3D torso object through information extracted by Google's ML pose detection API.

Google's pose detection API recognizes a person's body in a picture, still image, and video stream and extracts information about predefined landmarks in real time. The extracted landmarks information consists of the (x,y) value of the pixel coordinate system based on the corresponding image cut and the z value predicted through pose detection. But I can't use it directly as a 3D coordinate system because (x, y) and z are values of different coordinate systems.

So please explain the process of making (x', y', z') that can be used in any 3D space through (x, y) and z values.

FYI, In the extracted landmarks, the side facing the camera has a negative z value relative to the midpoint of the line connecting the left and right hips, and vice versa, if it is away from the camera, it has a positive z value.

Thanks for your help.

I have no idea for it.

Answer (score 0):

In the ML Kit dev doc, it says: "The origin of the Z axis is approximately the center point between the hips (left/right and front/back relative to the camera)." https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/pose-detection#z_coordinate

You could use that point as origin for X,Y as well: converting other landmarks's X,Y to be with origin of the center point between the hips.

In this case, the hip center will become the origin for all X,Y,Z. And you could draw all the 3D points out.